# imap_utf does weird things in browser but not php shell

Tags: php, character-encoding, email-headers

If I run this from a PHP script in a browser:

```
echo imap_utf8('X-My-Custom-Header: =?UTF-8?B?RXVnZW4gQmFiacSH?=');
```

I get this:

```
X-My-Custom-Header: Eugen BabicÌ
```

However if I do it through the PHP interactive shell, it correctly returns:

```
php > echo imap_utf8('X-My-Custom-Header: =?UTF-8?B?RXVnZW4gQmFiacSH?=');
X-My-Custom-Header: Eugen Babić
```

I have a script set up on the internet using a few decoding functions here: http://cameronsflash.com/misc/test.php as you can see none of them correctly decode the string (but in the interactive shell they do).

Why is it different in the browser and how do I fix it?

**Edit**: For some reason the accent on the c is not being displayed in the second example, but it is there in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're doing wrong: You're HTML (as generated by the PHP) is not UTF-8 encoded.

Add this to your `<head>`

tag:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```